# Talend Error Exception in component tPOP_1 (test) javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection timed out: connect;

Tags: talend, listpopupwindow

Please help me to find the solution for below error. i have tried using imap and pop3 setting, below are the configuration settings i have used

pop3:

Server name: outlook.office365.com

Port: 995

imap:

Server name: outlook.office365.com

Port: 993

Error im getting:

Exception in component tPOP_1 (test)

javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection timed out: connect;

nested exception is:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:479)

at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)

at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)

at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)

at accor.test_0_1.test.tPOP_1Process(test.java:769)

at accor.test_0_1.test.runJobInTOS(test.java:4959)

at accor.test_0_1.test.main(test.java:4727)

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)

at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)

at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)

at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)

at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

[FATAL]: accor.test_0_1.test - tPOP_1 Connection timed out: connect

Attached is the tpop component settings i have used.

[tpop component settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObQsb.png)

configuration settings i have used

pop3:

Server name: outlook.office365.com

Port: 995

imap:

Server name: outlook.office365.com

Port: 993

Comment: tPop should now use oauth to connect to outlook. You can't use a simple user/password to connect.  I think you won't be able to use this component on Talend Open Studio 7.3 . Did you try with talend 8 ? If you have a subscription product, there is a patch for it i think.

Comment: @Corentin exactly with the R2022-09 release you have an option to choose Microsoft Exchange

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this Java option in job jvm Parameters and try :

`-Dmail.imap.auth.plain.disable=true`

Link could help :

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/imap-setup-fails-with-authenticate-failed-error-in-logs-in-jira-server-185401609.html

Your component configuration is correct so if it doesn't work within these options that means that your organisation does bloc something

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft disabled Basic Auth. You won't be able to connect, unless you use OAuth token.

Talend 8 / 7.3 R2022-09 release introduced Microsoft Exchange Auth to tPOP that automatically exchanges the credentials. Configuration for that can be found in the official help document: https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/8.0/pop/configuring-an-oauth2-application-for-pop-and-imap

There's also a long answer on Talend community with all the details: https://community.talend.com/s/question/0D55b00007LRyrWCAT/tpop-microsoft-basic-authentication-retirement?language=en_US

Git repository for the component: https://github.com/Talend/tdi-studio-se/tree/master/main/plugins/org.talend.designer.components.localprovider/components/tPOP